# Flash Banner and PHP

Tags: php, flash

For some reason I'm trying to do:

```
<OBJECT id="affMV737" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" width="468" height="60">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.domain.com/view.php?banner_id=1">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.domain.com/view.php?banner_id=1" width="468" height="60" allowScriptAccess="always" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
</object>
```

I'm printing the FULL URL in the php but the flash is not loading...
but If i change the src in the flash code to the printed result in the php, the banner is working.

any advice?

thanks.

Comment: http://www.domain.com/files/bnrs/blabla.swf - for example.

Comment: you can't do this way. that `view.php` should return banner not banner url

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you want but I guess this will help

**instead of this:**

```
http://www.domain.com/view.php?banner_id=1
```

**try like this:**

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/view.php?banner_id=1');?>
```

**update:**

Another guess.. You need change your view.php to something like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash');
echo file_get_contents('http://domain.com/files/bnrs/blabla.swf');
```

Comment: no I need to take the Object code and put on many sites... the view.php help me to see how much views the banners... I cant tell to the sites owners to put your code... because some of them are ASP...